# How can I construct the equivalent of this PHP foreach() rendering in Vue.js?

Tags: html, vue.js

I know this is a very silly question but im new to vuejs and i would like to know how to convert this simple php code to vuejs

```
<div>
<?php
 foreach( $array as $key => $value){
  if($key == 0){
    echo '<div>'.$key.'</div>';
  }else{
   echo '<div>'.$value.'</div>';
  }
}
?>
<div>
```

it should go something like this :

```
<div>
 <div v-for="(item, key) in items" v-if="key == 0">{{key}}</div>
 <div v-else>{{item}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The condition in the for loop would break your else condition, try `<div v-for="(item, key) in items"><div v-if="key == 0">{{key}}</div>
 <div v-else>{{item}}</div></div>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<template v-for="(item, index) in items">
  <div v-if="index === 0">{{index}}</div>
  <div v-else>{{item}}</div>
</template>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9sd90474/29/)

Comment: Just fyi, this uses Vue version 1. In Vue version 2 (which I think the asker is using), the syntax would need to be `v-for="(item, index) in items"`.